# Why did I lose one reputation for downvoting an answer?

Tags: support, voting

Before we get started, I do not care that I lost the reputation. I'm trying to figure out why the reputation was taken away.

The answer that I downvoted did not answer the OP's question, hence the downvote. An answer should answer the question, which it simply did not do. So why exactly did I lose reputation for taking part in the community?

Picture for reference:

[image: picture of losing reputation]

The answer I downvoted is [How can I mount Microsoft OneDrive as a network drive in OSX?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218844/how-can-i-mount-microsoft-onedrive-as-a-network-drive-in-osx/237669#237669)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As documented in https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation:

> You lose reputation when:
>
> - your question is voted down: −2
> - your answer is voted down: −2
> - you vote down an answer: −1
> - you place a bounty on a question: − full bounty amount
> - one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags: −100

The reason downvotes impacts your reputuation is to prevent revenge or mass dowvotes against others. In addition it also emphasis the goal of AD (and SE sites in general) of getting *good* answers (which for instance means that instead of downvoting a bad answer it might be better both for you and for others to *up*vote good answers).

Comment: If someone else downvotes it as well, that means a variety of people agree, so shouldn't the reputation be awarded back? Also, I don't think 1 reputation would stop people from going on revenge sprees. Also, wouldn't taking reputation away discourage users from downvoting bad answers, and upvote them instead?

Comment: As I said, upvoting of good answers is prefered over downvoting of bad ones, so in a way this is intentional.

Comment: This was also in a situation where there wasn't a good answer yet, and a bad answer shouldn't be displayed as the first.